# Width prefixes to string constants

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c11

The latest version of the C standard provides for width prefixes to string constants e.g. `u8"a"` is a single preprocessing token.

Does whether you get one or two preprocessing tokens depend on the exact letters in the prefix? E.g. is it the case that `u9"a"` is still two preprocessing tokens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C11 specifies in `6.4` that a string literal is one of the pre-processing tokens:

```
preprocessing-token:
    header-name
    identifier
    pp-number
    character-constant
    string-literal
    punctuator
    each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
```

Hence `u8"a"` is a single token because the string literal section `6.4.5` lists that as a valid option:

```
string-literal:
    encoding-prefix(opt) " s-char-sequence(opt) "
encoding-prefix:
    u8
    u
    U
    L
```

The sequence `u9"a"` is *not* a string literal because `u9` is not one of the valid prefixes.

The `u9` would (from my reading) be treated as an identifier while the `"a"` would be a string literal, so that would be two separate pre-processing tokens.